# TCP server client or client server

Tags: networking, server, tcp, client, microcontroller

I am puzzled...

My project is a PC connected to multiple micro-controller boards in an isolated network. So far the protocol has been UDP which is easy to deal with, has no particular client/server but has its obvious shortcomings of lost messages when things get busy.

The micro-controllers have fixed IP-addresses (set by dip switches), the PC SW has a list of them, sends at present UDP messages to each of them and they reply to the address they came from (i.e. the PC) with status and/or data.

My question is now that I switch to TCP instead of UDP, should the PC be the listening server with many clients (could be anything from 1 - 50), or should the micro controllers be listening servers the PC can connect to as client? Note: controllers have fixed/known addresses - the PC does not.

An additional concern is re-connection. The micro-controllers are external and may lose connection, reset or otherwise need to connect again.

Thanks....

Comment: the only difference between the clind and the server in TCP is who sends the first SYN (first handshake packet to establish a connection). So the same logic. If the PC had a list of addresses, and microcontrollers replied to sender address, then PC should send the first SYN (client) and microcontrollers should establish connection with the address of the sender (server).

Comment: however, I would first ask. Do microcontrollers support TCP. Having TCP needs more resources. And does the way TCP handle lost packets actually the solution I need.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need to know. I feared that I was missing some important detail and I am glad to hear I am not. The micro-controllers are powerful PIC32MZ, so lots of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should the PC be the listening server with many clients (could be anything from 1 - 50), or should the micro controllers be listening servers the PC can connect to as client?

That is a basic design question that we cannot answer for you. Likely, it's more practical for arbitrary devices to connect to a central server but that's not a given.

> controllers have fixed/known addresses - the PC does not.

That might turn the previous question around.

> The micro-controllers are external and may lose connection, reset or otherwise need to connect again.

That's something you need to put into your design - have TCP connections time out and reconnect. Usually, a finite-state machine is useful here. You should also consider whether you use a one-shot connect-transmit-disconnect similar to UDP (easier to implement) or a longer TCP session with multiple data transmissions (more efficient).